# Setting background-image using jQuery changes background only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement, background-image

I'm trying to set `background-image` property of one element, depending on value of variable. It works only the first time. When I switch to ready, background image stops changing. Images themselves are small - around 8-10 kB.

This is my code:

```
if(status != '') {
    console.log('status');
    console.log(status);

    switch(status) {
        case 'dev':
            $('#status').css('background-position','0px -160px');
            break;
        case 'ready':
            $('#status').css('background-position','0px -240px');
            break;
        case 'soon':
            $('#status').css('background-position','0px 0px');
            break;
        case 'design':
            $('#status').css('background-position','0px -80px');
            break;
    }
    }
```

And here come CSS for the element:

```
#status {
z-index: 1;
float: right;
height: 80px;
width: 80px;
background: url(/images/front/status-sprite.png);
background-position: 0px -160px;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

Behavior didn't change. A background image does changes to ready, but doesn't change back.

**EDIT**: Code is updated using sprites generated by [csssprites.com](http://csssprites.com/).

Comment: Is the console (chrome) or firebug displaying something?

Comment: nope, not at all. no reports of file missing etc

Comment: After the 1st time, the images will not be loaded again from server (as cached in computer). I think it maybe the reason. I usually combine the images as a image sprite and shift the background position. Refer http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: is console.log(status) returning the right string? did you check the images path?

Comment: Don't use `background-image` (it causes lots sof problems for me), just use `background`

Comment: @steo - i checked it before i posted this question. console.log outputs the right string

Comment: So , like mifeng said, the solution could be a sprite image.

Comment: @steo did that. strangely problem persists!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, I'd suggest validating that the path exists to each image, you're trying to display. (although if the path is correct, you could override the stylesheet with the [`!important`](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) tag)

**Fiddles**

- [Background Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/killrawr/g6tJW/17/)
- [Sprite Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/killrawr/TZ4KH/3/)

Although it doesn't matter it isn't necessary to surround the `url()` on the [`background-image`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) property with `double quotations`.

```
$('#status').css('background-image','url(/images/front/status-design.png)');
```

Comment: I changed my code to use css sprites. see the updated version

Comment: @Elmor mind providing a [`link`](http://iforce.co.nz) to the sprite? and I'll mock something up. Did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: @Elmor based on the code, you've provided. It should work. See fiddles.