# changing colour of a background image with js on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking to changing image colours with javascript but the problem is that I need to change the background colour of an image - ie add a tint to it

so i have read a lot of posts on here and it seems possible when the html has a img in it (ie an src) but i cant find any solutions for a background image

So my css may have this in it

```
.productBenefits ul li {
background: url("tick.png") no-repeat scroll 0 4px transparent;
}
```

depending on the url for example i have different colours, and I need to colour this background image with the provided hex - so for example #ff0000

can anyone help?

Comment: Look at answer I provided on [jquery case set background-image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15944127/jquery-case-set-background-image/15944673#15944673), fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/killrawr/g6tJW/17/)

Comment: [Does this describe the effect you're going for?](http://users7.jabry.com/overlord/mug.html)

Comment: @Killrawr I need to have one image which I colour not a case statement for lots of diff images - but thanks

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that is actually the example i looked at - but that doesnt work with a background image

Comment: @Dan This can 100% be tuned to work with background-images. Give it a go, come back when you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AyyU6/1/

HTML:

```
Hover on the links, and see the result
<br>
<a href='#' data-color='#fff000'>Color 1</a>
<a href='#' data-color='#fffaaa'>Color 2</a>
<a href='#' data-color='#333000'>Color 3</a>
<a href='#' data-color='#123000'>Color 4</a>
<a href='#' data-color='#fff555'>Color 5</a>

<div style="width: 100px; height:100px;">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').mouseenter(function(){
   // Getting color information from the links data-color attr, of course it can be anything you define
   var color = $(this).attr('data-color');

   $('div').css('background-color',color);
})
```